# c code file is crashing and there is no error while compile

Tags: c, crash

i did all things right on my code and still there is a problem i dont know why

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node { 
    int data ; 
    struct node* link ; 
};
struct node* top = NULL ;
void pop(){ 
    if(top==NULL) 
        printf("element that will delete is %d\n",top->data);
    else {
        struct node* temp ;
        temp= top ; 
        top = top->link ;
        temp->link = NULL ; 
        free(temp);
        }}
void push() { 
    struct node* temp ;
    temp =(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    printf("please enter the data of the first node \n"); 
    scanf("%d",&temp->data);
    temp->link = top ; 
    temp = top ; 
} 
void printx(){
    if(top==NULL)
        printf("there is no element to print\n");
    else { 
        struct node* temp ; 
        while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n",temp->data) ;
        temp = temp->link ; 
        }


    }
}
int main() { 

    printf("please enter the type of operation u want to perform\n") ;
    printf("enter 1 for push , 2 for pop , 3 for print:  ") ;

    int x ; 
    scanf("%d",x) ; 
    switch(x){
        case 1 :    
            printf("\nu choosed push\n");
            push(); 
            break ; 

        case 2 :    
            printf("u choosed  pop \n"); 
            pop() ; 
            break ;

        case 3 :    
            printf("u choosed to print the element of the stack\n") ;
            printx(); 
            break ; 

    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: In pop you have this code: `if(top==NULL) 
        printf("element that will delete is %d\n",top->data);`.  Dereferencing a NULL pointer is guaranteed to crash.

Comment: `struct node* temp ; 
        while(temp != NULL) ...` you are checking an unitialized variable.

Comment: No compiler errors? Surely a warning about `scanf("%d", x);`? This should be `scanf("%d", &x);`

Comment: the first problem is the & in scanf but still there is a problem in pop function

Comment: Thank you for your kind acknowledgement.

Comment: how i can solve the NULL problem

Comment: @bruceg No it's not.  It's undefined behavior which means just that.  There are no guarantees what will happen.  Compile that with BDS C under CP/M and it most definitely will not crash when you dereference the NULL pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain "Dereference of a null pointer" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997165/can-someone-explain-dereference-of-a-null-pointer-warning)

Comment: If *still there is a problem*, then exactly what do you mean by *i did all things right on my code*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you paste this code at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ , then click "Debug" and then type `run` into the gdb window, it takes you to the line that creates the error.  (You can click the "help" button near the Debug button to get instructions on how to further use this tool.  Or you can google "gdb debugging" or "visual studio debugging" for further help.)

The error is on your `scanf` line.  If you google "scanf", you'll probably notice that int arguments pass the `address of` the int.  So you need `&x`, not `x`.  Your program has other errors, as well.  I suggest you make use of the help button mentioned above for the debugger, step through your program, and watch what's happening.  For instance, you'll notice your program immediately exits once you fix the first issue.  I imagine you'll want a loop to prevent that.  Further, in your pop, you're specifically checking if `top==null`, and then dereferencing it (`top->data`) if it is.  This is guaranteed to be illegal.  This is something you can check by running the debugger, selecting pop, and then printing the value (in the debugger) that your program is trying to access (`print top->data` in the gdb window)

Comment: You repeated a comment, but more original might be the "other errors" you mention.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Yeah, I'd consider pointing the OP at debugging resources the main contribution of this answer.  IMO that's clearly what's needed, as arbitrarily pointing at various issues with no hint as to how one might find them isn't likely to be helpful.  I did modify my answer slightly.

Comment: It's a good try, but hints about debugging and a link don't make an answer to the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Well, there's also an answer.  Not sure what else one would want except for me to debug the entire program.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Sorry--I'm beyond pissed because people are downvoting the crap out of this question, even though it's perfectly reasonable, if obvious to an experienced programmer, while providing basically no help.  My answer is far from perfect, but it beats downvotes, brief comments on the question that the op is likely to barely understand or are snarky and not helpful at all.  Anyway, point is apologies for the curt response...not really directed at you.

Comment: Not my DV but perhaps because there isn't any question about C asked. Just "my code is crashing".

Comment: @WeatherVane - Yeah, I get it.  Although I think the implied question, "Why is my code crashing?" is rather obvious.  Anyway, probably something for "meta".  Not that I'm likely to bring it up there.